# MYSQL - can a extra column is forced to update every time

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have a table with 3 column A, B, & C.
when ever some one update any column(A or B or both) it should update column C also.

Means someone cann't just write "update tableName set a=1, b=2 where blah blah". 
It should be always **"update tableName set a=something, b=something2, c=something3 where blah blah"**.
if someone don't do it, it returns some error.

i tried using trigger. But it didn't help me out. Below is the trigger that executed before update.

```
BEGIN 
  DECLARE TIMESTAMP DATE DEFAULT now();
  DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
  IF NEW.C IS NULL OR NEW.C = "" THEN
    SET msg = concat("Trying TO UPDATE NULL OR empty VALUE of C.");
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE "4500" SET MESSAGE_TEXT = msg;
  END IF;
END
```

New.C give the Existing Value of C in row

Comment: Where do you try to change C value ? In the given code, you don't put anything in C, you just try to read it's value...

Comment: Is this a `before update` trigger or an `after update` trigger?  For it to work, you need a `before update` trigger.

Comment: This is a before update trigger. just edit the question also. But it didn't work.